# Adobe Live cycle Designer

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

i want to generate pdf file using adobe live cycle and c# basically i done it by manually working like Design first pdf file using adobe live cycle designer and after using controls name like text box , check box and other controls   providing by adobe live cycle designer.but now i have an idea and want to implement , can it possible on design time we get all object of our projects in adobe live cycle designer
Code example

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileStream(TemplateFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(outputfile, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].Name[0]", "FirstName");
```